# Remove image contours

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to remove unwanted contours based on the following criteria.

1. X value must fall in the range 0 <= x <= image width
2. Y value must be equal to 0 or image height
3. The height of the contour should be in the range 0 <= h <= 30

The goal for the rules is to find contours that appear along the absolute top and bottom of the image. Here are two images for clarification.

These images are from one larger image. After splitting them into two separate images, partial characters remain which need to be removed. They fall along the top and bottom of the "new" images. Using the `cv2.rectangle` function to showcase which areas I'd like to remove. My issue is that I also get areas that do not follow the rules above as indicated by the red arrows.

Here is the code I am using.

```py
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(word, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for contour in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

    # top contours
    if (0 <= x <= word.shape[1] and y == 0):
        if (0 <= h <= 30):
            word[y:y + h, x:x + w] = 0
    # bottom contours
    if (0 <= x <= word.shape[1] and y+h == word.shape[0]):
        if (0 <= h <= 30):
            word[y:y + h, x:x + w] = 0
```

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

EDIT:

After searching some more and reading opencv docs I managed to solve the problem. I make a new image of the same size using `np.zeros(word.shape[:2], dtype=word.dtype)` then I drew the contours based on the criteria listed above using `cv2.drawContours`. Lastly, I subtracted the original image from the newly created one using `cv2.subtract(original, new)`

Comment: Could you check, whether they are removed as top or as bottom ones?

Comment: For the bottom ones, I am surprised that the exact equality `y+h == word.shape[0]` holds, since there is no pixel with coordinates `[word.shape[0], word.shape[1]]`

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is the "ryth" in the bottom image is all one connected component, and the "y" touches the bottom edge. Maybe use a morphological operator to erode the text first -- that might cause the letters to stop bleeding into each other.